# How many methods does this class have?

Tags: java

I have used the:

`System.out.println(Person.class.getDeclaredMethods().length);`

to get the number of methods of this class here:

```
    class Person {
private String name;
Person(String newName) {
name = newName;
}
public String getName() {
return name;
}
public void setName(String val) {
name = val;

}
}
```

I count three methods for this class but the `getDeclaredMethods().length` only computes two methods. What am I missing?

Comment: maybe constructor doesn't count?

Comment: A constructor doesn't count.. add `getDeclaredConstructors()` if you want to count constructors as well..

Comment: Thanks rzysia and TheLostMind.

Comment: Note: the class has all the methods it inherits from its parent i.e. `Object` as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That class declares (in order top to bottom):

- One field: `name`. (You can get information about declared fields using [`getDeclaredFields`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields--), but I don't think you're looking for that).
- One constructor: `Person(String)`. Constructors are not methods, they're constructors. If you want to know how many declared constructors there are, use [`getDeclaredConstructors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructors--).
- Two methods: `getName` and `setName`. You already know how to get them.

It *has* more methods than that, because it inherits the methods from `Object` (`toString`, `hashCode`, `equals`, etc.), but those are the ones it *declares*.

Answer (score 5):

```
Person(String newName) {
name = newName;
}
```

This is the contructor of class, not the method.

To understand the difference between the methods and constructors, please read this article: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076204/core-java/understanding-constructors.html